# Mean and Variance of dot product of two normalized random vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

I have two N-dimensions normalized vectors, **X** and **Y**; **X** ~ N($\mu$,$\Sigma$), $\mu$ is an N-1 vector and $\Sigma$ is the covariance due to **X** is normalized. **Y** is a const, what is the mean and variance of dot(**X**, **Y**)? Could you help me give an expression about $\mu$, $\Sigma$ and **Y**?

Comment: I'm sorry for mistaking you. The X is just an N-dimension vector, for example, N=3, the X is a unit sphere vector; we can drop the little i;

Comment: $\mathsf{dot}(X,Y)$ is the same as $Y^TX$ and if $Y$ is constant then $\mathbb EY^TX=Y^T\mathbb EX$ and $\mathsf{Cov}(Y^TX)=Y^T\mathsf{Cov(X)}Y$. Does that help here?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please give me some time to comprehend this.

Comment: but X is normalized, will this not influence the result? @drhab

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with the concept "normalized" to judge that. That is why I a gave a comment and not an answer. Personally I cannot find a reason why what I wrote in my former comment would not work.

Comment: @drhab there is still some difference using $Y^T E(x)$ when I use a lot of random points which are satisfy the Gaussian distribution, N($\mu$, $\sigma$) to test the real mean and variance; which depends on the $\mu$ and $\sigma$; Because $\mu$ is an N-1 dimension vector, we need to multiply a 1/$\sqrt{(1 + ||x||^2)}$ to transfer to a normalized N-dimension vector;

Comment: @drhab X = (x,1)/$\sqrt{(1 + ||x||^2)}$, we cann't directly use $\sqrt{(1 + ||\mu||^2)}$ to replace it;